# How can I set up gesture recognizer to interact any UIView when all the views are being animated?

Tags: uiview, core-animation, uigesturerecognizer, calayer

I found the code listed below from  https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo.  This particular method allows the user to stop a UIView while it is "in-flight" in a core animation sequence using a gesture recognizer.  When the view is tapped, the animation stops.  As shown this code will only work on animated view.  I have many animated views and I need interaction with any of the views.  I think I must set up an array of views (or layers) and cycle through them.  Is this correct?  How could I do this?  Thanks!

```
  /*
 This method gets called from a tap gesture recognizer installed on the view myContainerView.
 We get the coordinates of the tap from the gesture recognizer and use it to hit-test
 myContainerView.layer.presentationLayer to see if the user tapped on the moving image view's
(presentation) layer. The presentation layer's properties are updated as the animation runs, so hit-testing
the presentation layer lets you do tap and/or collision tests on the "in flight"   animation.
*/

- (IBAction)testViewTapped:(id)sender
{
  CALayer *tappedLayer;
  id layerDelegate;
  UITapGestureRecognizer *theTapper = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
  CGPoint touchPoint = [theTapper locationInView: myContainerView];
  if (animationInFlight)
 {
    tappedLayer = [myContainerView.layer.presentationLayer hitTest: touchPoint];
    layerDelegate = [tappedLayer delegate];

    if (((layerDelegate == imageOne && !doingMaskAnimation)) ||
      (layerDelegate == waretoLogoLarge && doingMaskAnimation))
    {
      if (myContainerView.layer.speed == 0)
        [self resumeLayer: myContainerView.layer];
      else
     {
        [self pauseLayer: myContainerView.layer];

    //Also kill all the pending label changes that we set up using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: animationStepLabel];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LOL. That demo project is mine. The code is written to find the layer that was tapped, and then use the fact that for a layer that backs a UIView, the layer's delegate is the view itself.

At the point in the code where it finds the layerDelegate, you should make sure it isKindOfClass UIView, then use whatever method is appropriate to match your view with the views you've animated. You could use an IBOutletCollection to keep track of the views that you are animating, or manually create a mutable array and add view objects to it, use view tags, or whatever makes sense for your application.